# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in the following line of code in python3.5.

```
path = os.getcwd().strip('/n')
Null,userprof = subprocess.check_output('set USERPROFILE', shell=True).split('=')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Decode before using `split` funtion

```
Null,userprof = subprocess.check_output('set USERPROFILE', shell=True).decode('utf-8').split('=')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is adding `text=True` to `check_output`:

`path = os.getcwd().strip('/n') Null,userprof = subprocess.check_output('set USERPROFILE', shell=True, text=True).split('=')`