# Changing Python2 to Python3 Error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, string, byte, python-3.8

I am new to python and yet have been tasked with the conversion of a file unfamiliar to me from python2 to python3. One problem in particular has plagued me.
I started with:

```
graphical_users = [line.split() for line in check_output("who".split('\n') if " :0" in line]
```

I then changed it to

```
graphical_users = []
        for line in check_output("who").split('\n'):
                if " :0" in line:
                    graphical_users.append(line.split())
```

for easier debugging and found the line

```
for line in check_output("who").split('\n'):
```

to be the culprit.

Either way since they are equivalent, it gave me the error:
"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"
I then looked to see if other have this problem and most places talk about people opening files in binary mode or whatnot but as far as I can tell, that is not the case here.
If anybody has any suggestions I would be open to try anything. Also, if other code is needed just let me know.

Comment: Where are you defining `check_output`?

Comment: Check_output is an import from subprocess, Here's the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I had used decode but not with those specifications!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [enzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9997212/enzo)! He found information showing that it needed a decode method between check_out("who") and .split('\n') making the solution:

```
for line in check_output("who").decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
```

More information about this error is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983589/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-subprocess-check-output)